# ConstraintLayout inside Row with IntrinsicSize.Min height

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

i have an issue in **placing ConstraintLayout as Row's Child (Compose Version : 1.1.1)**. when set the **height of Row to `IntrinsicSize.Min`**, **the content of ConstraintLayout gets corrupted**, ie it's width gets narrow and all children are placed in that narrow width.
here's the code

```
 Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min) ) {
       ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier){
          .
          . 
          .
        }
}
```

and here are screenshots

before putting inside Box:

[image: before putting in Box]

after :

[image]

here's  ConstraintLayout Content:

```
  Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(roundedCornerSize),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp,
            color = Color.Gray),
        color = Color.Green,
        elevation = elevation) {

        ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Blue)
            .padding(16.dp)) {
            val (dragIconRef, imageRef, nameRef, updateTimeRef, priceRef, changeRef) = createRefs()
            val endMarginFromImageStart = 8.dp

            Icon(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(dragIconRef) {
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                linkTo(top = parent.top, bottom = parent.bottom)

            }, painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_drag_indicator),
                contentDescription = null)

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(imageRef) {
                        end.linkTo(dragIconRef.start, margin = 16.dp)
                        linkTo(top = parent.top, bottom = parent.bottom)

                    }
                    .size(36.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_notify),
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(nameRef) {
                    top.linkTo(imageRef.top)
                    end.linkTo(imageRef.start, margin = endMarginFromImageStart)
                },
                text = itemModel.name,
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(updateTimeRef) {
                    bottom.linkTo(imageRef.bottom)
                    end.linkTo(imageRef.start, margin = endMarginFromImageStart)
                },
                text = itemModel.updateTime,
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(priceRef) {
                    baseline.linkTo(nameRef.baseline)
                    end.linkTo(changeRef.end)
                },
                text = itemModel.price,
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(changeRef) {
                    baseline.linkTo(updateTimeRef.baseline)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                },
                text = itemModel.change.toString(),
            )


        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: you can check the code now